# How to quickly read a large txt data file (5GB) into R(RStudio) (Centrino 2 P8600, 4Gb RAM)

Tags: r, large-data

I have a large data set, one of the files is 5GB. Can someone suggest me how to quickly read it into R (RStudio)? Thanks

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r) maybe, though there are some new packages appeared since then.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with and the file contents. If it's a csv file you can use `sqldf` to filter it as if it were a SQLite database and only load what you want. If you *must* load everything, `fread` is still the fastest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have 4 GBs of RAM you cannot put 5 GBs of data 'into R'. You can alternatively look at the 'Large memory and out-of-memory data' section of the [High Perfomance Computing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) task view in R. Packages designed for out-of-memory processes such as [ff](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html) may help you. Otherwise you can use [Amazon AWS services](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx37RSKRFDQNTSL/Statistical-Analysis-with-Open-Source-R-and-RStudio-on-Amazon-EMR) to buy computing time on a larger computer.

Comment: Actually, you can if you use Revolution R's distribution. It doesn't require all data to be loaded in memory. This won't make loading 4GB at once any faster though

Comment: No, you cannot. Revolution R uses out-of-memory algorithms like ff does. You still cannot load more data than you have RAM.

Answer (score 1):

My package `filematrix` is made for working with matrices while storing them in files in binary format. The function `fm.create.from.text.file` reads a matrix from a text file and stores it in a binary file without loading the whole matrix in memory. It can then be accessed by parts using usual subscripting `fm[1:4,1:3]` or loaded quickly in memory as a whole `fm[]`.